# Show that $\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \sin \left(\frac{x}{k+1}\right)\right| \leq |x|$ for all $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $$ f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \sin \left(\frac{x}{k+1}\right). $$ I need to show that $|f(x)| \leq |x|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Here's what I have so far:
$$ \left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \sin \left(\frac{x}{k+1}\right)\right| \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|\frac{x}{k(k+1)}\right| = |x| \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right| \leq |x|\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1}\right)$$

However, both these series diverge, so I'm not sure how I can get an upper bound on them to make the result hold. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=\lim_{M\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{M}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=\lim_{M\to +\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{M+1}\right)=\color{red}{1}.$$